# Difference between toggle() and Toggle

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am learning Modals in SwiftUI and the code is below:

ContentView.swift:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingAddUser = false
    var body: some View {
      return  VStack {
        Text("Modal View")

        }.onTapGesture {
            self.showingAddUser.toggle()
            print(self.showingAddUser) //for console
        }

        .sheet(isPresented: $showingAddUser) {
            Addview(isPresented: self.$showingAddUser)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

AddView.swift:

```
import SwiftUI

    struct Addview: View {
        @Binding var isPresented: Bool
        var body: some View {
            Button("Dismiss") {
                       self.isPresented = false
                   }
        }
    }

    struct Addview_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            Addview(isPresented: .constant(false))
        }
    }
```

When I try to run the code for the first time and check the `print` output in console, boolean value changes to `true` however if I initialise `@State` variable `showingAddUser` with `true` the console output is unchanged that is it remains `true`. Should't `toggle()` flip the boolean value to `false`?

Is this `toggle()` different from `Toggle` switch from a concept point of view?

Comment: There is a Swift bug with `toggle` and property attributes (`@State`). It would work with standard `self.showingAddUser = !self.showingAddUser`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `toggle()` is a mutating function on value type `Bool`. If you set the initial value of `showingAddUser` as `true` it will display the `AddUser` View when launched initially and it's not if set to `false`, that's the difference.

`Toggle` is a SwiftUI View. It can be used as any other View in SwiftUI body, like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var bool: Bool
    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: $bool) {
            Text("Hello world!")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> There is no need for isPresented Boolean in Add View
>
> Try This

ContentView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
       @State private var showingAddUser = false
       var body: some View {
       return  VStack {
               Text("Modal View")

       }.onTapGesture {
              self.showingAddUser = true
              print(self.showingAddUser) //for console
       }

       .sheet(isPresented: $showingAddUser) {
             Addview()
       }
    }
 }

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

AddView.swift

```
import SwiftUI
struct AddView: View {

    var body: some View {
        Button(action:
             // Do Your Things
        ) {
            Text("MyButton")
        }
    }
}

struct Addview_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Addview()
    }
```

Comment: Toggle() is used for changing states like show & hide password.

Comment: In this case, if you want to show another view, then you don't need to use toggle.
Next time, it will automatically assign false value to it. There is no need to Toggle()